# Find the first page of a MultiPage in dart-pdf

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, header

I am creating PDF document using dart-pdf. It contains various sections that could be any number of pages in length. Each section starts on a new page. Currently I am adding a new `MultiPage` to the document for each section. How can I place a heading on **only** the first page of a given `MultiPage`

```dart
...
myPdf.addPage(
  MultiPage(
    header: (Context context) {
      //discover first page of this MultiPage here ???
      if(isFirstPage) {
        return Header()
      }
    }
  )
)

myPdf.addPage(
  MultiPage(
    header: (Context context) {
      //discover first page of this MultiPage here ???
      if(isFirstPage) {
        return Header()
      }
    }
  )
)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all cases, you can do something like:

```dart
var isFirstPage = true;

myPdf.addPage(
  MultiPage(
    header: (Context context) {
      //discover first page of this MultiPage here ???
      if(isFirstPage) {
        isFirstPage = false;
        return Header()
      }
    }
  )
)
```

https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/707#issuecomment-852458481

Answer (score 5):

My solution (ho header on first page):

```
MultiPage(
  header: (pw.Context context) {

    if (context.pageNumber == 1) {
      return pw.Container();
    }

    return ...; 
  )
```